# how to run ZK app in firefox?

Tags: firefox, zk

I want to run my aplication on firefox, or any other external web browser. zk script is only shown correctly in eclipse internal web browser, what can I do for visualising in firefox too?

Comment: ZK is just a Java Servlet web framework, it is agnostic to the browser you use to view it. You may see some discrepancies in terms of CSS or JavaScript behavior between browsers, but this is not expected. If you are having problems, you need to describe the problem to get help from the community - what have you tried, what's not working, what's the expected behavior and what is the errant behavior.

Comment: To me it sounds like you're trying to open the `.zul` files in your Browser. But they need to be processed by a Java Server. Its working in eclipse because it brings it's own local debug server.
It seams like you missunterstood the concepts. Please read the docs on the ZK Website.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is firefox plugin, I didn't tried my self but here are the links:

[Zk Jet at mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/zk-jet/)

[Zk Jet at zkoss.org](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Jet)

ZK Jet is a browser extension available for Firefox and Google Chrome which provides the user with a ZK sandbox environment.